# Webdriver IO opening multiple chrome instances in parallel even though I haven't specified the tests to run in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver-io

When I run wdio test, I see multiple chrome instances opening up parallelly even though I haven't specified the tests to run in parallel.

My **package.json** contains:

```
  "scripts": {
    "node-inspector": "node-inspector --debug-port 5859 --no-preload",
    "test": "node node_modules/.bin/wdio ./test/config/suite.jasmine.conf.js",
    "allure-report": "node_modules/.bin/allure generate ./test/reports/allure-results && allure report",
    "junit-report": "node_modules/.bin/junit-viewer --results=./test/reports/junit-results --save=junit-results.html && open junit-results.html",
    "generate-report": "./node_modules/.bin/allure generate  --clean && ./node_modules/.bin/allure open"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^5.22.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^5.22.4",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^6.1.5",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.3.5",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.3.2",
    "grunt-jasmine": "^0.1.0",
    "grunt-webdriver": "^3.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "selenium-standalone": "^6.15.4",
    "wdio-allure-reporter": "^0.8.3",
    "wdio-testrail-reporter": "^1.1.5",
    "webdriverio": "^6.1.7"
  },
...
```

my test>config>suite.jasmine.conf.js contains:

```
specs: [
     './test/specs/Lightning/Lead/lightning_leadRouting.spec.js' 
],

 maxInstances: 1,
 services: ['devtools', 'chromedriver','selenium-standalone'],
 framework: 'jasmine',
...
```

I am running the test with command: `npm test`

This opens up many browsers in parallel even though there is only one test to execute. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with wdio and jasmine dependencies I used, Once I upgraded to the latest versions, the issue was solved. I guess multiple browsers were spun up on failure because I set connectionRetryCount: 3 and wdioRetries: 3.

It's fixed now.
Upgraded Wdio and Jasmine dependencies to the latest versions, added
"chromedriver": "^89.0.0",
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0" and then did an 'npm install' from the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

This issues is basically because of the dependencies mismatching with Versions.

1. Run 'npm update' in the terminal, update all node dependencies
2. Update the chrome browser
3. Restart both the browser and the IDE

This is applicable if the behavior is same in other browsers too.

Good day guys. Happy Learning & Coding...